# Module not found while it is already installed

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

I face a very basic error, yet I couldn't find any solution on similar topics that also work for my case. I want to use the module `dateparser` on Python, so I installed it using `pip install dateparser` on a cmd.

When using `import dateparser` on Python, I have: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateparser'`

Here is what I have when I retry to install it using `pip install dateparser`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: dateparser in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from dateparser) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex!=2019.02.19 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from dateparser) (2020.11.13)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from dateparser) (2020.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from dateparser) (2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil->dateparser) (1.15.0)
```

Here is my sys path:

```
['',
'c:\\users\\hp\\anaconda3\\python37.zip',
'c:\\users\\hp\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
'c:\\users\\hp\\anaconda3\\lib',
'c:\\users\\hp\\anaconda3',
'c:\\users\\hp\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
'c:\\users\\hp\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'c:\\users\\hp\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'c:\\users\\hp\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

I work using Sublime Text 3, thanks in advance !

Comment: Try `pip install --user dateparser`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, here is the result: 

Requirement already satisfied: dateparser in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from dateparser) (2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from dateparser) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from dateparser) (2020.5)

Comment: Try `conda install dateparser` since it appears you're using anaconda.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I also tried it but it didn't worked. I also tried to work with pandas and encountered the same problem, it might be a Path problem ? I don't know how to manipulate Paths